# Structures in C

Tags: c, loops, indexing, struct, cs50

I've faced with a problem in PSET4 (whodunit). I really don't understand why errors occure in the next case below, although compile doesn't make a warning.

In this problem I should read each pixel of given .bmp file, substitute each red pixel by white pixel and write new image in a new .bmp file.

Here are 2 versions of my code. In the first listing there is a correct version of code, and program works correctly as I wanted. In the second listing there is an example of code, that successfully compiled, but pixels either still the same, or happens smth strange.

**CORRECT VERSION**

```
// iterate over infile's scanlines
for (int i = 0, biHeight = abs(bi.biHeight); i < biHeight; i++)
{
    // iterate over pixels in scanline
    for (int j = 0; j < bi.biWidth; j++)
    {                                                  //CORRECT VERSION
        // temporary storage
        RGBTRIPLE triple;

        // read RGB triple from infile
        fread(&triple, sizeof(RGBTRIPLE), 1, inptr);
        if((triple.rgbtRed == 0xff) && (triple.rgbtGreen == 0x00) && (triple.rgbtBlue == 0x00))
        {
            triple.rgbtBlue = 0xff;
            triple.rgbtGreen = 0xff;
            triple.rgbtRed = 0xff;
        }

        // write RGB triple to outfile
        fwrite(&triple, sizeof(RGBTRIPLE), 1, outptr);
    }
```

**INCORRECT VERSION**

```
// iterate over infile's scanlines
for (int i = 0, biHeight = abs(bi.biHeight); i < biHeight; i++)
{
    // iterate over pixels in scanline
    for (int j = 0; j < bi.biWidth; j++)
    {                                                  //INCORRECT VERSION
        // temporary storage
        RGBTRIPLE triple[i][j];

        // read RGB triple from infile
        fread(&triple, sizeof(RGBTRIPLE), 1, inptr);
        if((triple[i][j].rgbtRed == 0xff) && (triple[i][j].rgbtGreen == 0x00) && (triple[i][j].rgbtBlue == 0x00))
        {
            triple[i][j].rgbtBlue = 0xff;
            triple[i][j].rgbtGreen = 0xff;
            triple[i][j].rgbtRed = 0xff;
        }

        // write RGB triple to outfile
        fwrite(&triple, sizeof(RGBTRIPLE), 1, outptr);
    }
```

According to the "arrays" lessons (and to example with "students" structure in CS50), it is required thing to include indexes [i] and [j] for the arrays and structs variables during "for"-loop executing. But in this case everything's getting invalid, if I put those indexes in the code. And everything is OK if I do not write those indexes. Why does this logic break here, with structures?

Comment: You... what have you done.

Comment: @Havenard  what's wrong?

Comment: As pointed out by dasblinkenlight in his answer, you are supposed to specify the index of the array when you access it, not when you declare it. When declaring it you should specify its total size, which ranges from the index 0 to size-1. And if you are handling one element per iteration you are supposed to declare the array outside the loop, as if you do it inside the loop, it will be re-declared each time and there might be inconsistencies in it (aka undefined behavior).

Comment: You also don't need an array in this case since you read and write each element individually and never really need all of them loaded in memory simultaneously.

Comment: @Havenard thanks for help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you declare `RGBTRIPLE triple[i][j];` you make a 2D array with valud indexes `0..i-1` and `0..j-1`. Accessing `triple[i][j]` is undefined behavior; that's why your second solution fails.

However, you do not need a whole array of `RGBTRIPLE`, because you process them one at a time. That is why your first solution works.

If you need to read the whole array, declare it *before* the outer loop with correct dimensions:

```
RGBTRIPLE triple[abs(bi.biHeight)][abs(bi.biWidth)];
```

Be careful with this solution, because you may cause a crash for very large values of `bi.biHeight*bi.biWidth`.